# WPF Fastdrawing for Audio visualation

Tags: c#, wpf

As part of my audio libary i would like to create a sample visualisations.
I know how I get the values I want to draw like fft results and so on. 
But the main problem is that I don t know whats the best way to draw them. I have quite a lot of experience in using wpf but I never had to do something like this. What should I use to keep performance as good as possible?

Comment: You might look into [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).

Comment: I am not clear on what visualizations you are attempting, but perhaps this will help: http://istudio.codeplex.com/. I can only guess that it may help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different approaches you can take, depending on the quality you need, memory usage, and performance....here are just some.

- create a new object derived from FrameworkElement, and then inside draw the "visual" aspect dynamically by drawing onto a DrawingContext during OnRender.  Drawings have a much lower overhead than other WPF elements such as Shapes, Image, etc. However, it still may not scale well if you have 1000s of elements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619.aspx
- WriteableBitmapEx....it will give you the drawing primitives you need to write into a Bitmap directly. http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ .. see this for some demos which are spookily similar to what you would do for an audio visualization. http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/03/advanced-animation-animating-15000-visuals-in-silverlight-2/
- use DirectX with Direct2D. This offers DirectX like performance, but you would need to use COM interop or C++/CLI code wrappers to make it available to your .NET C# code. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct2D-with-WPF

Some other links:

- http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/